# Testing pyspark with local aws glue images, can't consume kinesis data

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis

I'm testing a streaming pipeline using pyspark and AWS Glue Image,  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/develop-and-test-aws-glue-version-3-0-jobs-locally-using-a-docker-container/

In particular I'm using `amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01.`

This image authenticates with my personal .aws folder configuration, I can publish data on kinesis using this configuration and this script runs inside the docker image

```
import boto3
import json
import uuid

kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis', region_name='us-east-1')

stream_name = 'test-stream'

data = {'key': {'key_nested': 'value_nested'}}

partition_key = str(uuid.uuid4())

encoded_data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')

response = kinesis_client.put_record(
    StreamName=stream_name,
    Data=encoded_data,
    PartitionKey=partition_key,
)

print(response)
```

but when I try to read data using pyspark using (also this is run inside the container)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from datetime import datetime


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KinesisExample") \
    .getOrCreate()



df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kinesis") \
    .option("streamName", "test-stream")\
    .option("region", "us-east-1")\
    .option("initialPosition", "TRIM_HORIZON") \
    .load()


query = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

no data is showed in console and after a while I get the error:
 `pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: Query [id = 220696e6-6926-4571-8fdb-746adb77ad5a, runId = e2d63c79-8065-4647-9c18-86a97c607237] terminated with exception: Error while List shards`

I think there is no auth problems, since I can publish data and the credentials provided have Full Admin Access. I tried also with an S3 sink, but the problem seems related to that spark can't find that stream. Region and stream name are correct.

Did someone faced the same issue?

I tried to pull data using console and s3 sink but no data was written